# Древовидная структура данных в django

Tags: база-данных, django, сортировка

Имеется модель подразделений

```
class Subdivision(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Наименование', max_length = 200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Данные выводятся с помощью запроса `subdivision = Subdivision.objects.all()`, в не отсортированном виде. Например в базе есть данные:

```
+----+------------------------+--------+
| id |          name          | parent |
+----+------------------------+--------+
|  1 | Управление             | null   |
|  2 | Производственный отдел | 1      |
|  3 | Бухгалтерия            | 1      |
|  4 | Производственный цех   | 2      |
+----+------------------------+--------+
```

Все это выводится так:

1. Управление
2. Производственный отдел
3. Бухгалтерия
4. Производственный цех

А нужно так(сохраняя иерархию):

1. Управление
2. Производственный отдел
3. Производственный цех
4. Бухгалтерия

Т.е. первым идет подразделение с нулевым полем `parent`, потом идут дочерние подразделения, потом дочерние подразделения дочернего подразделения, и т.д. Можно ли такую сортировку реализовать с помощью django.

Comment: Думаю, реализовывать это с помощью django нет никакого смысла, нужное дерево легко строится вручную обычным питоном

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил таким способом, добавил в модель поле `order`. При сохранении добавляю туда что-то подобии пути.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Subdivision)
def pre_save_subdivision(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if(instance.parent==None):
        instance.order='1'
    else:
        old = sender.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0].id
        instance.order = instance.parent.order + '.' + str(old+1)
```

Дальше сортирую `Subdivision.objects.all().order_by('order')`. В итоге:

```
+----+------------------------+--------+-------+
| id |          name          | parent | order |
+----+------------------------+--------+-------+
|  1 | Управление             | null   | 1     |
|  2 | Производственный отдел | 1      | 1.2   |
|  3 | Бухгалтерия            | 1      | 1.3   |
|  4 | Производственный цех   | 2      | 1.2.4 |
+----+------------------------+--------+-------+
```

И выводится так как мне нужно:

1. Управление
2. Производственный отдел
3. Производственный цех
4. Бухгалтерия

Answer (score 1):

Можно, конечно:
`subdivision = Subdivision.objects.all().order_by('parent')`

order_by - сортирует по указанному полю. Если поставить минус вначале `.order_by('-parent')`, то отсортирует в обратном порядке.

Comment: Данный вариант мне не подходить. Как было так и остается, никакой иерархии.